# How do I get a field count from an executed query?

Tags: 7, database

I'm sure this exists, but after a few dozen searches, I'm not any closer to an answer.

After I've executed a query in Drupal (for example)

```
$dbParts = db_select("parts", "p")
    ->fields("p")
    ->execute();
```

How can I get a count (or list) of fields without pulling this first record? With MySQL I was able to use "mysql_num_fields".

**UPDATE**

Just to give a little background... I have some old code (using mysql_* functions) that export data to the DBF format. In order to format the header of the DBF, I need to have a field count (and information about the fields) even if the record count is 0 in order to format a "blank" database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal uses PDO, whose equivalent function is [`PDOStatement::columnCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php):

> Returns the number of columns in the result set represented by the PDOStatement object. If there is no result set, PDOStatement::columnCount() returns 0.

So what you're looking for isn't totally possible these days. I can't see a Drupal equivalent of `columnCount()`, but you can always grab the PDO connection object with [`Database::getConnection()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/Database%3a%3agetConnection/7), and work with that directly if it'll help you get part of the way there.

To take a different approach, and assuming you've used the schema API to describe your table to Drupal, you can query that instead:

```
$table = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('MYMODULE', 'table_name');
$fields = $table['fields'];
```

Comment: I just tried $dbParts->columnCount() and it actually works. So I guess the Drupal object is some sort of extension of the 'PDOStatement' object (making it's built in functions available). Thanks! =)

Comment: Sweet, didn't know that!

Comment: Didn't know that?? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/class/DatabaseStatementBase/7 `class DatabaseStatementBase extends \PDOStatement implements DatabaseStatementInterface`

Comment: @chx Just never looked, thinking about it I've used PDO methods on a `SelectQuery` before so on _some_ level I guess I knew ;)